# override does not work inside extension object in swift

Tags: swift, swift4.2

We're trying to upgrade our based swift version to 4.2 recently. Unfortunately, found plenty of issues while upgrading it. One of them we could not fix current is:

got that error in following code:

> Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported

```
extension  MyHelpTableViewCell {
    override class var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyHelpTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
```

Please help me how to solve that issue if you have had experience. Many thanks.

**UPDATE:**
If I've added @objc and dynamic like that,

```
class MyHelpTableViewCell: WMHelpTableViewCell {
}

extension MyHelpTableViewCell {
    @objc class dynamic var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyHelpTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
```

following got same error,

> Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

You have to move the overriding method from the `extension` into the `class`

---

Or you have to mark the declaration in the base class with `@objc` and `@dynamic`

```
class BaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @objc class dynamic var identifier : String { return "something" }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question as adding code you mentioned above

Comment: No, the `@objc ... dynamic` must be added to the declaration in the **base** class

Comment: I've created another `MyHelpTableViewCell` based on `WMHelpTableViewCell` class and it has own individual `nib` class. Based class `WMHelpTableViewCell` has its own `nib` called `WMHelpTableViewCell ` and sub class `MyHelpTableViewCell` has its own `nib` called `MyHelpTableViewCell`. That's why it cannot be moved those to based class.

Comment: There are only those two options to override a property. Maybe you could use a method instead.

Comment: I've updated my question again. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: You can't declare and override any method or variable within the extension. Override it within main declaration of class instead of extension

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same without extension as follows:

```
class WMHelpTableViewCell {
    var identifier: String!
}

class MyHelpTableViewCell : WMHelpTableViewCell {
    override var identifier: String? {
        get {
            return self.identifier
        }
        set {
            self.identifier = newValue
        }
    }
}
```